# Vue.js app gets sights info and images using Google Places API.I'm getting "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, google-places-api

I'm currently getting an error

`"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()"`

for each sight when I load the component that displays all sights. The interesting thing is that sometimes everything works as intended but occasionally, some (not all) of the images don't load and I get the aforementioned error.

This makes me wonder if the problem is on my end or if Google Places API is experiencing some problems. This has happened several times over 2-3 weeks.

```
<img class='sight-photos' :src="'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=300&photoreference=' + sight.photos[0].photo_reference + '&key=mykey'">
```

Comment: You have an invalid key. Should it be like this: `'&key='+mykey">`?

Comment: In my code, mykey is replaced by my real key. I have done this since I don't want to share my real key here.

Comment: All right. Maybe you exceed usage limits? Check Google Cloud Platform Console for current usage.